# data not saving on the table in the database laravel 8

Tags: laravel

am trying to save some data in a table but it doesn't save.ive have added all the necessary code but still it doesn't work..instead on submitting the data its displays on the URL on the browser..here is my code
the method in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'first_name'=>'required|min:5|max:40',
        'last_name'=>'required|min:5|max:40',
        'phone'=>'required',
    ]);

    $address=new Deliveryaddress;
    $address->user_id=0;
    $address->county_id=$request->countyname;
    $address->city_id=$request->cityname;
    $address->first_name=$request->first_name;
    $address->last_name=$request->last_name;
    $address->phone=$request->phone;
    $address->street_address=$request->street_address;
    $address->save();

    dd($address->save());

    return redirect('/checkout')->with('success_message','Your Delivery Address has been added');
 }
```

here is my form in the blade file

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('address.store') }}" class="form">
                                        @csrf
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="country-select">
                                                <label>Country <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <select name="countyname" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>Choose Your County</option>
                                                    @foreach($delivaddresses as $address)
                                                        <option value="{{ $address->id }}">{{ $address->county }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                                <label>Town / City <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Town/City" name="cityname" class="form-control input-md {{ $errors->has('cityname') ? 'error' : '' }}" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                                <label>Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Street address/Village Name Apartment, suite, unit etc. (optional)" name="street_address"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                                <label>First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" class="form-control input-md {{ $errors->has('first_name') ? 'error' : '' }}" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                                <label>Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" class="form-control input-md {{ $errors->has('last_name') ? 'error' : '' }}" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                                <label>Company Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Company Name" name="company_name" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="checkout-form-list">
                                                <label>Phone <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Phone Number" name="phone" class="form-control input-md {{ $errors->has('phone') ? 'error' : '' }}" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Submit</button>
                                    </form>
```

here is my model

```
class Deliveryaddress extends Model
         {
              use HasFactory;
              protected $table = 'deliveryaddresses';
              protected $fillable = 
                   ['user_id','first_name','last_name','street_address','phone','county_id','city_id'];
         }
```

here is my route

```
Route::resource('address',Address_Controller::class);
```

where might i have gone wrong with my code..

Comment: Can you share your routes.web.php file?

Comment: ive added it on the question

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: you dd() before the return

Comment: nop no error @qadirpervez

Comment: okay they you need to debug, try running `dd($request->all())` on the first line in your `store` method and check if you are getting your inputs correctly

Comment: it reloads and nothing shows..same as before @qadirpervez

Comment: then your form submit is not going to the expected place, do check your middleware
try checking your route list `php artisan route:list` and see if everything works as expected

Comment: Maybe some validation error is redirecting you back to the form. Try removing the validation from the controller to see what happens

Comment: Unrelated fyi, "country" and "county" are two different things

Comment: @qadipervez the route am submitting data to is perfect as per the route...@porloscerros upon submitting data the data displays at the URL section of browser

Answer (score 0):

the code is perfect i had made a syntax error in my blade file...i include the submitting form inside another form